# FIndFragmentByTag fails after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use an `UIless` retained `Fragment` not to lose Service Binders during orientation change. The problem is that in the Activity `onCreate` the `findFragmentByTag` always returns null.

This is my activity:

```
public abstract class AbstractLearnActivity extends Activity implements FragmentCallbacks {
    private final static String BINDER_FRAG_TAG = "AbstractLearnActivity.BINDER_FRAG_TAG";

    private BinderFragment binderFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        //do some initialization stuff...

        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(BINDER_FRAG_TAG);
        if(fragment != null){
            Log.i("asd", "Binder Frag already exists");
            binderFragment = (BinderFragment)fragment;
        }
        else{
            Log.i("asd", "Binder frag is null");
            binderFragment = new BinderFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction().add(binderFragment, BINDER_FRAG_TAG).commit();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

While this is the fragment:

```
public class BinderFragment extends Fragment {
    private Application application;

    public BinderFragment(){
        Log.i("asd", "Constructor called for binder fragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity){
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if(application == null){
            application = activity.getApplication();
            //make connections...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy(){
         Log.i("asd", "binder fragment destroyed");
         super.onDestroy();
         //disconnect services
     }
}
```

If I run the application and try to change the orientation I get:

```
<application started>
I/asd﹕ Binder frag is null
I/asd﹕ Constructor called for binder fragment
I/asd﹕ Attaching
<orientation change>
I/asd﹕ Is fragment found? true
I/asd﹕ Binder frag is null
I/asd﹕ Constructor called for binder fragment
I/asd﹕ Attaching
<orientation change>
I/asd﹕ Is fragment found? true
I/asd﹕ Binder frag is null
I/asd﹕ Constructor called for binder fragment
I/asd﹕ Attaching
<application closed>
I/asd﹕ binder fragment destroyed
I/asd﹕ binder fragment destroyed
I/asd﹕ binder fragment destroyed
I/asd﹕ Is fragment found? false
```

As you can see the Fragment is there when the activity is destroyed, and it's correctly retained (since they are all destroyed when the application is closed), but the `onCreate` fails to find it and creates a new one... Anyone as any idea about why I cannot retrieve the Fragment by tag?

Thanks for your help ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just taking a shot here,

why have you placed the call to `super` and `setContentView` after Fragment transaction commit. In onCreate method, first call `super` then `setContentView` and then fragment transaction.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        //do some initialization stuff...

       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager(); //suggestion to use supportFragmentMan
       binderFragment = (BinderFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_SEARCH_ARTIST_FRAGMENT);

       if(binderFragment == null){
            binderFragment = new BinderFragment();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(binderFragment , BINDER_FRAG_TAG).commit();
       } 
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It actually helps. If I call the FragmentManager after the `onCreate` it works. Alas I need the `binderFragment` before I can call the `onCreate`, so I need to refactor my code... But you indeed solved that particular problem ^^